# How to "try start" one thread from several other threads, java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I wrote this in my function:

```
if(myThread.isAlive()) {
} else {
myThread.start();
}
```

but this is unsafe if many threads call this function the same time. start a running thread throws an exception.

So except putting try-catch around it, do I have other options?

Comment: If you are not planning on doing anything when the thread is alive, just not the result `if(!myThread.isAlive()) {myThread.start();}`

Comment: @unholysampler, this Will NOT work w/o sync on the thread

Comment: @bestsss: Of course. This is why I just posted it as a comment, it does not address the question at all.

Answer (score 3):

Make this method synchronized. Also, this check (`isAlive()`) is unsafe because if the thread have been finished you cannot start it again (and `isAlive()` will return false...)

Comment: yep. the thead is always recreated when the thread ends. that's not a problem. and my goal is not to make this method synchronized because i want other threads to call it the same time.

Comment: @karl - it's hard for me to see a reason why you would want accessing to some object (not necessarily thread) by more than on thread **at the same time** this is a recipe for problems. And I think you can restart the thread once it ends. This should cause IllegalStateException. I would go with creating new thread instead.

Comment: if(myThread.isAlive()) {
} else {
synchronized(thread) {
    if(thread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW)
        thread.start();
}
} ---> this is my solution . thx though.

Comment: @karl - Pretty much what I meant, but the check for isAlive is unnecessary, since `thread.getState()` covers this case as well. Good luck!

Comment: @karl - in SO, if you get an answer that answers your question well, you mark it as accepted (the tick left to the answer) if one of the answers satisfied you (either Peter's, Antony's or mine), please mark it as accepted, so people will not think you are still looking for an answer.

Comment: the simplest and robust way is relying on the IllegalThreadStateException, not state and not isAvile

Answer (score 1):

I would only create the thread when I intend to start it.

What you can do is

```
synchronized(thread) {
    if(thread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW)
        thread.start();
}
```

A thread which has finished will not be alive, but it cannot be retstarted.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [syncronized method / block](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html)? Use [locks](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html)?

Answer (score 0):

contrary on what everyone might tell: do not use isAvile() or getState(), both require to execute them into a sync. block along w/ thread.start() and requires that the thread actually uses itself as monitor (de-facto it does so)

instead, just catch the exception (`IllegalThreadStateException`) of start() and ignore it.

```
try{
  thread.start()
}catch(IllegalThreadStateException _x){
//ignore or log the reason, use getState(), if need be
}
```